# iOS Client/Server - should I use GameCenter?

Tags: iphone, ios, client-server, game-center

First time developing a client/server game and was wondering if anyone can give me some pointers. Should I just use GameCenter? Should I write my own? (Similar to what DrawSomething creators did)

I have a basic demo of a GameCenter implementation working but I don't know the ups/downs of using it- are there any? Should I just develop my own to have full customization but lose out on a weekend of free time?

Any insight is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: if a weekend is all it takes for you to have you own fully customized game center in the hopes of making a huge load of money I would suggest you lose that weekend of free time :)

Comment: lol it wouldn't take me a weekend to have my own fully customized one, but it would only take that to have simple communication between two clients and a server and I could build from there- security and all those other perks would be left out... I'm thinking GameCenter might just be the best thing, maybe I can branch it out after I release it for version 2 or something!

Comment: I did not yet integrated with game center but from my experience with other games it is very useful and can save you many development hours. Unless you really need something unique I suggest you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GameCenter and similar services are very common and most iOS users have an account there. From users view I prefer it when developer uses the GameCenter. (Saves users creating another account, let them see all their friends stats without searching them and much more.)

An advantage of implementing a own 'GameCenter' is (like the DrawSomething) that it could be cross platform.

Altogether nobody can take this decision for you. My personal opinion is you should just use GameCenter, since I'm sure you won't get a solution which is a good as the original GameCenter.