# Easiest framework for developing turn-based game on iOS?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, game-center

I'm planning to build a Turn-based game and I'm looking at the various options and wondering which is the best way to go?

There's Game Center and the turn-based API in iOS5, but that seems to be a pretty tough road to go down, and there's just about 1 [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1) (I'm new to obj-c) online to help get that going

Or maybe it's better to go with another API, maybe something like [this](http://gameminion.com/)

Are there any oher options, or is that pretty much it? I'm looking for the most straightforward option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how complicated your game is. The nice thing about Game Center is that it's free (vs Game Minion) and Apple supports it (vs running your own server).

I'd say Game Center is the most straight forward option. Ray's tutorial is very good, and you'll probably become a better objective-c programmer by using Game Center vs another solution.

edit: With Mac OS X Mountain Lion bringing Game Center to Macs, it's technically cross-platform once Mountain Lion is released this summer.

Comment: I'm probably going with Game Center, the only issue I would say is that when I've already used it for scores, the scores don't update in the leaderboards in sandbox mode, so hopefully there won't be any similar issues with turn-based.

Comment: I believe score updates are a bit slow, especially on sandbox. I'm using Game Center for my new game and if I open it up on 2 devices, I can literally end a turn on device 1 and instantly see it become my turn on device 2.

Comment: @Phil in sandbox mode, the scores will start updating as soon as you also send scores using a distinct device

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look here: [iOS Client/Server - should I use GameCenter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212036/ios-client-server-should-i-use-gamecenter)

Game Center seems to be a natural choice for this. Another advantage is that your game will be  listed in Game Center browser which means more downloads and more profit for you.

A most important disadvantage: Game Center is not cross-platform, and never will be.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely go with Game Center. We still don't know what iOS 6 will bring but I'm feeling that Game Center will evolve more. It is pretty easy to get something simple up and running after a few days of investigation and effort. As Brian said, Ray's tutorials are great about it, if you really want to learn about it, you should consider buying his book "iOS by Tutorials", also Apress has a book completely on Game Center.

Comment: I agree I'm looking for some new things to be announced at the next conference.

Answer (score 0):

The posts here have it spot on, if you have relatively simple requirements and your target platform is iOS, then you can't go wrong with Game Center. 
Integration is pretty straight forward and there are plenty of info to get you up and running. Plus there is a lot of experience here that could help.

If you are looking to support multiple platforms and have the need for extra bells and whistles, then I would recommend you look at our service; Game Minion http://gameminion.com .